# jQuery Selectors - Select text within a specific tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

Here is my code snippet:

```
   <div class="totals">
            <table id="shopping-cart-totals-table">
        <col />
        <col width="1" />
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
        <td style="" class="a-right" colspan="1">

            <strong>Grand Total</strong>
        </td>
        <td style="" class="a-right">
            <strong><span class="price">$364.99</span></strong>
        </td>
    </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>

            <tr>
        <td style="" class="a-right" colspan="1">
            Subtotal    </td>
        <td style="" class="a-right">
            <span class="price">$354.99</span>    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="" class="a-right" colspan="1">

            Shipping & Handling (Flat Rate - Fixed)    </td>
        <td style="" class="a-right">
            <span class="price">$10.00</span>    </td>
    </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

How would I use jQuery to select the first span of class "price" and assign the "$364.99" text within that tag to a variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var total = $('.price:first').text();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do like this:

```
var price = $('span.price').first().text();
```

Or any of these:

```
var price = $('span.price:first').text();
var price = $('span.price:eq(0)').text();
var price = $('span.price').eq(0).text();
var price = $($('span.price').get(0)).text();
var price = $($('span.price').get()[0]).text();
```

Comment: jQuery's `get` returns the DOM object, which doesn't have a `text()` function.

Comment: @a'r: Right, it does. I kept the examples with an added wrapper although they get a bit convoluted, just to show the different ways of accessing elements.

Comment: Thank you for the response Guffa - great ideas, however to be fair a'r was the first one to respond to my specific inquiry, so I chose his response as the solution.

Comment: @user589294: Well, I *did* actually answer 19 seconds before him... ;)

Comment: @user589294: Point to the text that says for example "5 hours ago", and the tooltip will show you the exact time.

Answer (score 2):

To get the text

```
$(".price").eq(0).text()
```

To set the text

```
$(".price").eq(0).text('12.21$')
```

Comment: jQuery's `get` returns the DOM object, which doesn't have a `text()` function.